# Getting error while refreshing "adminhtml/sales_order_totals" block through AJAX

Tags: magento-1.9, sales-order

[image]

I am developing custom module, in which i'm adding custom block **sales->order** edit page with field price that update total paid price (Order Totals) block. But while refreshing

```
adminhtml/sales_order_totals
```

block, i got an error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getOrder() on a non-object \app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Block\Order\Totals.php on line 67
```

After clicking to "Add button", It call saveAction() controller

```
public function saveAction() 
{ 
    $modelOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(100015)->setGrandTotal(300)->save(); 
    return $this->_forward('successajax');
```

}

and **$this->_forward('successajax');** call to below controller

```
public function successajaxAction()
{ 
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
        Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_totals')->setTemplate('sales/order/totals.phtml')->toHtml()
    );        
}
```

On ajax response, We replace **Order Totals** block will showing me bellow error.

[image]

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: please provide full details about your custom module., like block, controllers, config etc

Comment: I have custom form in **admin->sales->order** that submit price field to saveAction() controller.


`public function saveAction() {  
$modelOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->setGrandTotal(500)->save();

return $this->_forward('successajax');
}`

'public function successajaxAction()
    { 
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_totals')->setTemplate('sales/order/totals.phtml')->toHtml()
        );
    }'

Comment: We need to get that error, which is coming, so for that need full code and file description, after examine which we can go forward for solution, so please edit your question and add your code description on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With lots of crazy research and after spending full day on this, I found solution of my question.

I have to override **OrderController.php** file in **config.xml**

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <!-- Override OrderController -->
        <adminhtml>     
            <use>admin</use>           
            <args>
                <orderupdate>
                    <NameSpace_ModuleName before="Mage_Adminhtml">NameSpace_ModuleName</NameSpace_ModuleName>
                </orderupdate>                    
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

and override file in NameSpace/ModuleName/controllers/Adminhtml/OrderController.php

```
<?php 
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php';
class NameSpace_ModuleName_Adminhtml_OrderController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController
{    
    public function saveAction() {  
        if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) { 

            try {
                $modelOrder = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($data['order_id'])
                ->setGrandTotal($data['custom_price'])
                ->save();

                /** Initialize order **/
                $order = $this->_initOrder(true);                               
                $this->_initAction();

                $response = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/sales_order_totals')->setTemplate('sales/order/totals.phtml')->toHtml();

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                $response = array(
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   => $this->__('Cannot update price. Please refresh page.')
                );
                $response = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response);
            }
            $this->getResponse()->setBody($response);
        }
    }                    
} ?>
```

I think this may help other people that facing issue like this.